# Problem while defining variables in racket

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I am trying to create a recursive function which picks n items from a list returning the picked values and the list without the values, but when I create my variables I get this error:

```
new-list: unbound identifier in: new-list
```

Here is my code:

```
(define(pick-randomr list n picked) ;;Picked always called as empty list
  (if(= n 0) (values list picked)
     ((let* ([aux list]
             [r (random (length aux))]              
             [value (list-ref aux r)]
             [new-picked (cons value picked)]
             [new-list (values (remove value aux))])
        (values aux r new-list))
      (pick-randomr new-list (- n 1) new-picked))))
```

EDIT:
The line that goes:

```
 (values aux r new-list)
```

is just to not have an empty body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your syntax:

- You should not use `list` as a parameter name, it conflicts with a built-in procedure of the same name.
- Don't surround `let*` with *two* brackets, that's a common mistake, brackets *are not* like curly braces in other languages, you must not use them to define a block of statements, use `begin` for that - but we don't need it in this particular case.
- The first error you got stated that you must *not* define a `let*` with an empty body. But the expression you added there isn't right, you *must* write the expressions that use the variables inside the `let*`, otherwise the `new-list` variable won't be visible.

This is what you meant to write:

```
(define (pick-randomr lst n picked)
  (if (= n 0)
      (values lst picked)
      (let* ([aux lst]
             [r (random (length aux))]              
             [value (list-ref aux r)]
             [new-picked (cons value picked)]
             [new-list (values (remove value aux))])
        (pick-randomr new-list (- n 1) new-picked))))
```

Let's test it:

```
(pick-randomr '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 '())
=> '(1 2 5)
   '(3 4)
```